# How to protect your API from developers who knows your API?

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, microservices, webapi

I'm a fullstack developer trainee in a company. I'm working on Online book store project. My manager asked a question.

He asked "**If someone i.e other developer knows your code or API they can change the code or API in your project and adds themself as an admin or can remove some user from the DB and also performs CRUD operations by changing your API. So how can you solve this?**".

My suggestion: Rather than having codes in the local machine we can put our code in some server.

plz suggest your opinion and correct answer.

Comment: I think [this](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/collection/developers-collection/principles/protect-your-code-repository) article is a quite nice way to bring someone a brief vision about source code security.

Comment: we can use the header in API when getting the response. In the Header, we use a key then the condition is PHP code where the key is the change you cannot get a response.if someone knows your key then getting a response. This trick is to protect your response data.

Comment: What about API gateways??

Comment: so anybody has unconditional access to version control system and can do changes? It doesn't make sense to develop protection if you can't control who can do changes in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use a code repository like `github` or `gitlab`. After uploading your project as a repository, change the setting of the repository such that no one else is allowed to update the code (No other Contributors). Your project code in production should be deployed based on this repository.
Not just update, you could also make your repository private so that no one could see your code.

Comment: How can I change the setting of the repository such that no one else is allowed to update the code?.....You mean having private repo??

Comment: @Arivazhagan no, it could be public. But you can define who contributes to the project. If you do not allow any one else as a contributor to the project, then no one would be able to commit any changes in the main repository. They could still fork a public repository and make changes in their local machine. But since there are not allowed to merge their changes to the main repository it will not go to production. If you want no one to see your code, then you need to make it private.

Comment: Usually in an organization, only the senior folks would have the access to update the code. So junior folks would make updates in the code from their local machine and put a `merge request` (gitlab term). This merge request needs to be approved by someone who has the right to make updates. Only if it is approved, the code would reach main repository.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your question is mostly related to the runtime behavior or control over a rest service. Thats where the security comes in to play. Gateway plays a role by filtering the resource path. The API endpoint he knows can be filtered or remapped at Gateway. Securing the application via Authentication and Authorization adds another layer of protection. for example. Person A can only access the application if he/she is authenticated. Once Authenticated, person A can add him/herself only if the person is of category SystemAdmin etc.

If its related to the Code Management then repository management comes in to play. Set rights to few individuals for pushing the changes to the Master branch. All developers logically should be working on Forked branch and will create a Pull Request to push the changes to the Master branch. This will give the opportunity to the moderators of Master branch to review the code and filter it out.